# Authentication strategy between my chome extension and server

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I'm in the process of building a Google Chrome extension, and have some questions about how to implement security into the application.

I need to access a couple of Google API's so am going to be using OAuth 2.0 for that. So basically from the extension I know which user is logged into the browser.

My extension then needs to get and post data to my (nodejs) API service. I want to ensure that the user requesting data is the same user that is logged into the browser. Is there any way of using the previous Google authentication process to also authenticate communications between the extension and my API? I dont really want the user to have to log in again, to access my API.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, and I've not been able to find anything that fits this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [OpenID Connect auth flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) and you will get an [access_token and an id_token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode). The acess_token you will use to use to make authenticated requests to Google APIs as usual. The id_token will be used as authentication with requests to your server.

When the requests hit your server you will need to [validate the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken) and you can then use the contents of the id_token to [identify the user](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo).

Comment: ah right I thought it would be something like this, thanks. I didn't know about the token validation and wasn't sure the token was something I could share between servers etc. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

User wouldn't have to login on auth process provided if user is already logged in and you are using a web application flow (not `chrome.identity` APIs) but user would see the consent screen atleast the first time. However you can skip the account selector screen if you already know the email address by providing `&login_hint=` parameter.

Comment: While this doesn't directly help me, i can see this info being useful a bit down the track thanks.